# node.js and juggernaut pub/sub

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, express, juggernaut

I'm using express framework and juggernaut. I looked at many examples about juggernaut, all examples using this method(client side):

```
  var jug = new Juggernaut;
  jug.subscribe("channel_name", function(data){
    console.log("Got data: " + data);
  });
```

Is it secure? I don't think so, everybody can subscribe to a channel from javascript console. Is there a way to subscribe a channel from server side?

Comment: What should be insecure about it? Also, do you you want to subscribe to Juggernaut that's running on **another** server, or on the same one?

Comment: I take the example from here: https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut. As you can see, you can subscribe to a channel from browser. I want private channels in my application, so this way is insecure for me. I want to check session then allow subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Use security through obscurity, use a random channel name (HMAC).

Comment: Indeed I'm finding this is the only way to have somewhat secure channels in most pubsub systems (PubNub, Redis also)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Juggernaut works, but I know that Faye supports extensions that can include authentication, so that subscribe operations require a valid token. See: http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html

It would be worth checking whether Juggernaut supports a similar extension/intercept model.